# How to create grok/json filter to parse the below json format

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I want to parse this JSON to Kibana using Logstash

```
{
"Format": "IDEA0",
"ID": "2b03eb1f-fc4c-4f67-94e5-31c9fb32dccc",
"DetectTime": "2022-01-31T08:16:12.600470+07:00",
"EventTime": "2022-01-31T01:23:01.637438+00:00",
"Category": ['Intrusion.Botnet'],
"Confidence": 0.03,
"Note": "C&C channel, destination IP: 192.168.1.24 port: 8007/tcp score: 0.9324",
"Source": [{'IP4': ['192.168.1.25'], 'Type': ['CC']}]
}
```

I want that ID, Detect Time, Event Time, Category, Confidence, Note, Source is a single field so later i can do visualization in kibana.

Here's what I'm already trying to do

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/StratosphereLinuxIPS/output/*.json"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}

filter {
        json {
                source => "message"
        }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "test-test"
                user => "***"
                password => "***"
        }
        stdout{}
}
```

But the field is not separated correctly

[image: Kibana Discover]

Any help will be meaningful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

:::UPDATE:::

I already found the solution (Help by other guys from Elastic forum but not 100% optimize need to tweak it a little more)

Here's the Logstash Conf I'm using if someone needs it in the future

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/StratosphereLinuxIPS/output/alerts.json"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
                codec => multiline { pattern => "^{$" negate => "true" what => "previous" }
        }
}

filter {
        mutate {
                gsub => ["message", "'", '"']
        }
        json {
                source => "message"
        }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "test-keempat"
                user => "xxx"
                password => "xxx"
        }
        stdout{ codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Thanks !